# getting null value from itemList in base adapter

Tags: android

im working on custom calendar, every thing working properly, but the problem is when click on grid(which is button in my case) that time i m getting null value from my model (Attendance_items).

please help me.

here is my activity

```
   public class My_Attendance extends BaseActivity implements OnClickListener {

private TextView currentMonth;
private ImageView prevMonth;
private ImageView nextMonth;
private GridView calendarView;
private GridCellAdapter adapter;
private Calendar _calendar;

private int month, year;
String ResponseResult;
String webMethName;
String currentMonthForAttendanceDetails;
String currentYearForAttendanceDetails;

private List<Attendance_items> itemsOfAttendance = new ArrayList<Attendance_items>();

private final DateFormat dateFormatter = new DateFormat();
private static final String dateTemplate = "MMMM yyyy";
private ProgressDialog progressDialog = null;
String userId;
String schoolId;
int thisYear;
int thisMonth;
int thisDay;

int totalDays = 0;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.my_attendance);

    SessionManager sessionManagerNgo = new SessionManager(My_Attendance.this);
    HashMap<String, String> typeOfUser = sessionManagerNgo.getActiveUser();
    userId = typeOfUser.get(SessionManager.KEY_USERID);
    schoolId = typeOfUser.get(SessionManager.KEY_SCHOOLID);
    mydb = new DataBaseHelper(this);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    thisYear = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    thisMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
    thisDay = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    prevMonth = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.prevMonth);
    prevMonth.setOnClickListener(this);

    nextMonth = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.nextMonth);
    nextMonth.setOnClickListener(this);

    calendarView = (GridView) this.findViewById(R.id.calendar);

    _calendar = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());
    month = _calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
    year = _calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);

    currentMonth = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.currentMonth);
    currentMonth.setText(DateFormat.format(dateTemplate, _calendar.getTime()));

    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Please Wait.");
    progressDialog.show();

    getAttendanceDetails(month, year);

    adapter = new GridCellAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.id.calendar_day_gridcell, month, year, itemsOfAttendance);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    calendarView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private void setGridCellAdapterToDate(int month, int year) {

    totalDays = 0;

    adapter = new GridCellAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.id.calendar_day_gridcell, month, year, itemsOfAttendance);
    _calendar.set(year, month - 1, _calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    currentMonth.setText(DateFormat.format(dateTemplate, _calendar.getTime()));
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    calendarView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v == prevMonth) {
        if (month <= 1) {
            month = 12;
            year--;
        } else {
            month--;
        }
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Please Wait.");
        progressDialog.show();
        getAttendanceDetails(month, year);
        setGridCellAdapterToDate(month, year);
    }
    if (v == nextMonth) {
        if (month > 11) {
            month = 1;
            year++;
        } else {
            month++;
        }
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Please Wait.");
        progressDialog.show();
        getAttendanceDetails(month, year);
        setGridCellAdapterToDate(month, year);

    }
}

private void getAttendanceDetails(int month, int year) {
    currentMonthForAttendanceDetails = String.valueOf(month);
    currentYearForAttendanceDetails = String.valueOf(year);

    AsyncCallWS task = new AsyncCallWS();
    task.execute();
}

public class AsyncCallWS extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        webMethName = "P_MonthWiseAttendanceDetails";
        userId = "120032";
        schoolId = "13";
        int currentMonthForAttendanceDetails = month;
        int currentYearForAttendanceDetails = year;
        ResponseResult = Common_Webservice.ShowAttendanceDetailsForParents(userId, schoolId, currentMonthForAttendanceDetails, currentYearForAttendanceDetails, webMethName);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void res) {
        if (ResponseResult.equals("Details Not Found")) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(My_Attendance.this);
            builder.setTitle("Result");
            builder.setMessage("Attendance Details Not Available For this Month.");
            AlertDialog alert1 = builder.create();
            alert1.show();
        } else if (ResponseResult.equals("No Network Found")) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(My_Attendance.this);
            builder.setTitle("Result");
            builder.setMessage("There is Some Network Issues Please Try Again Later.");
            AlertDialog alert1 = builder.create();
            alert1.show();
        } else {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(ResponseResult);

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        Attendance_items attendanceItems = new Attendance_items();
                        attendanceItems.setAttendanceId(obj.getString("Attendance_id"));
                        attendanceItems.setStudentId(obj.getString("Student_Id"));
                        attendanceItems.setSwipCardNo(obj.getString("SwipCard_No"));
                        attendanceItems.setSchoolId(obj.getString("School_Id"));
                        attendanceItems.setMachineId(obj.getString("Machine_Id"));
                        attendanceItems.setMachineNo(obj.getString("Machine_no"));
                        attendanceItems.setGroupId(obj.getString("Group_Id"));
                        attendanceItems.setAttType(obj.getString("Att_Type"));
                        attendanceItems.setAttDate(obj.getString("Att_Date"));
                        attendanceItems.setAttTime(obj.getString("Att_Time"));
                        attendanceItems.setAttStatus(obj.getString("Att_Status"));
                        attendanceItems.setTrkSms(obj.getString("Trk_Sms"));
                        attendanceItems.setPresentDate(obj.getString("PresentDate"));
                        attendanceItems.setPresentMonth(obj.getString("PresentMonth"));
                        attendanceItems.setPresentYear(obj.getString("PresentYear"));

                        itemsOfAttendance.add(attendanceItems);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

here is my adapter class

```
      public class GridCellAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements OnClickListener {
    private static final String tag = "GridCellAdapter";
    private final Context _context;

    private final List<String> list;
    private static final int DAY_OFFSET = 1;
    private final String[] weekdays = new String[]{"Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"};
    private final String[] months = {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"};
    private final int[] daysOfMonth = {31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};
    private int daysInMonth;
    private int currentDayOfMonth;
    private int currentWeekDay;
    private Button gridcell;
    private TextView num_events_per_day;
    private final HashMap<String, Integer> eventsPerMonthMap;
    private final SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
    List<Attendance_items> itemsDetails;

    // Days in Current Month
    public GridCellAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, int month, int year, List<Attendance_items> itemsOfAttendance) {
        super();
        this._context = context;
        this.list = new ArrayList<String>();
        this.itemsDetails = itemsOfAttendance;
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        setCurrentDayOfMonth(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        setCurrentWeekDay(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));
        // Print Month
        printMonth(month, year);
        // Find Number of Events
        eventsPerMonthMap = findNumberOfEventsPerMonth(year, month);

    }

    private String getMonthAsString(int i) {
        return months[i];
    }

    private String getWeekDayAsString(int i) {
        return weekdays[i];
    }

    private int getNumberOfDaysOfMonth(int i) {
        return daysOfMonth[i];
    }

    public String getItem(int position) {
        return list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    private void printMonth(int mm, int yy) {
        int trailingSpaces = 0;
        int daysInPrevMonth = 0;
        int prevMonth = 0;
        int prevYear = 0;
        int nextMonth = 0;
        int nextYear = 0;

        int currentMonth = mm - 1;
        String currentMonthName = getMonthAsString(currentMonth);
        daysInMonth = getNumberOfDaysOfMonth(currentMonth);

        GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(yy, currentMonth, 1);

        if (currentMonth == 11) {
            prevMonth = currentMonth - 1;
            daysInPrevMonth = getNumberOfDaysOfMonth(prevMonth);
            nextMonth = 0;
            prevYear = yy;
            nextYear = yy + 1;
        } else if (currentMonth == 0) {
            prevMonth = 11;
            prevYear = yy - 1;
            nextYear = yy;
            daysInPrevMonth = getNumberOfDaysOfMonth(prevMonth);
            nextMonth = 1;
        } else {
            prevMonth = currentMonth - 1;
            nextMonth = currentMonth + 1;
            nextYear = yy;
            prevYear = yy;
            daysInPrevMonth = getNumberOfDaysOfMonth(prevMonth);
        }

        int currentWeekDay = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - 1;
        trailingSpaces = currentWeekDay;

        if (cal.isLeapYear(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR)))
            if (mm == 2)
                ++daysInMonth;
            else if (mm == 3)
                ++daysInPrevMonth;

        // Trailing Month days
        for (int i = 0; i < trailingSpaces; i++) {
            list.add(String.valueOf((daysInPrevMonth - trailingSpaces + DAY_OFFSET) + i) + "-GREY" + "-" + getMonthAsString(prevMonth) + "-" + prevYear);
        }
        // Current Month Days
        for (int i = 1; i <= daysInMonth; i++) {

            String mydate = (String.valueOf(i) + " " + getMonthAsString(currentMonth) + " " + yy);
            SimpleDateFormat inFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("d MMM yyyy");
            Date date = null;
            try {
                date = inFormat.parse(mydate);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            SimpleDateFormat outFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");
            String currentDayName = outFormat.format(date);

            if (i == getCurrentDayOfMonth()) {
                list.add(String.valueOf(i) + "-BLUE" + "-" + getMonthAsString(currentMonth) + "-" + yy);
            } else {
                list.add(String.valueOf(i) + "-WHITE" + "-" + getMonthAsString(currentMonth) + "-" + yy);
            }
        }
        // Leading Month days
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size() % 7; i++) {
            list.add(String.valueOf(i + 1) + "-GREY" + "-" + getMonthAsString(nextMonth) + "-" + nextYear);
        }
    }

    private HashMap<String, Integer> findNumberOfEventsPerMonth(int year, int month) {
        HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        return map;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) _context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_attendance_gridcell, parent, false);
        }
        num_events_per_day = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.num_events_per_day);
        // Get a reference to the Day gridcell
        gridcell = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.calendar_day_gridcell);
        gridcell.setOnClickListener(this);

        // ACCOUNT FOR SPACING
        String[] day_color = list.get(position).split("-");
        String color = day_color[1];
        String theday = day_color[0];
        String themonth = day_color[2];
        String theyear = day_color[3];

        gridcell.setText(theday);
        gridcell.setTag(theday + "-" + themonth + "-" + theyear);

        String myCurrentDate = theday + " " + themonth + " " + theyear;
        SimpleDateFormat inFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("d MMM yyyy");
        Date date = null;
        try {
            date = inFormat.parse(myCurrentDate);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        SimpleDateFormat outFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");
        String currentDayName = outFormat.format(date);


        //for event
        if ((!eventsPerMonthMap.isEmpty()) && (eventsPerMonthMap != null)) {
            if (eventsPerMonthMap.containsKey(theday)) {
                num_events_per_day = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.num_events_per_day);
                Integer numEvents = (Integer) eventsPerMonthMap.get(theday);
                num_events_per_day.setText(numEvents.toString());
            }
        }
        // Set the Day GridCell
        gridcell.setText(theday);
        gridcell.setTag(theday + "-" + themonth + "-" + theyear);

        //checking to add day for remaining space of month and add next n previous months date

        if (day_color[1].equals("GREY")) {
            gridcell.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.lightgray02));
            gridcell.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorwhite));
        }
        //checking for actual days of month
        else if (day_color[1].equals("WHITE")) {
            if (currentDayName.equals("Sunday")) {
                gridcell.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorred500));
                gridcell.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorwhite));

            }
        }
        //checking for current date
        else if (day_color[1].equals("BLUE")) {
            if (currentDayName.equals("Sunday")) {
                gridcell.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorred500));
                gridcell.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorwhite));
            }
        }
        return row;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        //add event for each date and show it{timing}
        if (view.getId() == R.id.calendar_day_gridcell) {
            Attendance_items listItems = new Attendance_items();

            String inTime = "In Time : " + listItems.getAttTime();
            String outTime = "Out Time : " + listItems.getAtt_OutTime();
            String attendanceType = "Type : " + listItems.getAttType();
        }
    }

    public int getCurrentDayOfMonth() {
        return currentDayOfMonth;
    }

    private void setCurrentDayOfMonth(int currentDayOfMonth) {
        this.currentDayOfMonth = currentDayOfMonth;
    }

    public void setCurrentWeekDay(int currentWeekDay) {
        this.currentWeekDay = currentWeekDay;
    }

}
```

here is my layout

```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/lightgray"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/buttonlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:gravity="left|top"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/prevMonth"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_20sdp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:src="@drawable/calendar_left_arrow_selector" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/currentMonth"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_40sdp"
        android:layout_weight="0.6"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/nextMonth"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_20sdp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:src="@drawable/calendar_right_arrow_selector" />

</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/daysLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/buttonlayout"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_5sdp"
    android:background="@drawable/calendar_days">


</RelativeLayout>
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/calendar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/daysLayout"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_5sdp"
    android:numColumns="7">
</GridView><RelativeLayout>
```

here is gridLayout

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/calendar_button_selector"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/calendar_day_gridcell"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/_3sdp"
    android:background="@drawable/calendar_button_selector"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="#000000" >
</Button>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/num_events_per_day"
    style="@style/calendar_event_style"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/_10sdp"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_10sdp"
    android:layout_gravity="right" >
</TextView>
```

in onclick method getting null value from Attendance_items.
what i did wrong?

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        //add event for each date and show it{timing}
        if (view.getId() == R.id.calendar_day_gridcell) {

           for(int i = 0; i <itemsDetails.size(); i++) {
                listItems = itemsDetails.get(i);
                if(listItems.getPresentDate().equals(day)){
                    inTime = "In Time : " + listItems.getAttTime();
                    clickedDate = "Date : " + listItems.getAttDate();
                    outTime = "Out Time : " + listItems.getAtt_OutTime();
                    attendanceType = "Type : " + listItems.getAttType();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

please try this. hope it helps

```
Attendance_items listItems = new Attendance_items();
```

this is null. you are not setting anything in listItems

Now the final solution is declare your button in getView `final Button btn = (Button) vi.findViewById(R.id.btn);` like this. and add `btn.setonclicklistner` after declaration and add `onClick` code in `btn.setonclicklistner`. then you easily get position there. Hope now this helps you

Comment: using this ( itemsDetails.getAttTime(); ), i didnt get getAttTime();

Comment: you have to declare Attendance_items listItems = new Attendance_items(); in getView() and after that you have to add data from itemsDetails.get(position) to listItems. and then fetch listItems in your onClick @pratikSonawane

Comment: i get only last items from listItems when i click on any gridcell..i didnt get grid position when i clicked on particular grid.every time i get last item.

Comment: Now the final solution is declare your button in getView final Button btn = (Button) vi.findViewById(R.id.btn); like this. and add btn.setonclicklistner after declaration and add onClick code in btn.setonclicklistner. then you easily get position there. Hope now this helps you

Comment: try this properly and if this helps please mark this as a correct answer. for more detail http://stackoverflow.com/q/26752670/7320259 check this code. My office is close now. will meet you tomorrow

Comment: thanx buddy done it. i made some changes and now its working properly. @Zaki Pathan

Comment: in my onclick listerner i done this..for(int i = 0; i <itemsDetails.size(); i++) {
                    listItems = itemsDetails.get(i);
                    if(listItems.getPresentDate().equals(day)){
                        inTime = "In Time : " + listItems.getAttTime();
                        clickedDate = "Date : " + listItems.getAttDate();
                        outTime = "Out Time : " + listItems.getAtt_OutTime();
                        attendanceType = "Type : " + listItems.getAttType();
                    }
                }

Comment: happy to help you @pratikSonawane :) :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    //add event for each date and show it{timing}
    if (view.getId() == R.id.calendar_day_gridcell) {
        Attendance_items listItems = new Attendance_items();

        String inTime = "In Time : " + listItems.getAttTime();
        String outTime = "Out Time : " + listItems.getAtt_OutTime();
        String attendanceType = "Type : " + listItems.getAttType();
    }
```

you try to get value from a new item……Of course it's null

Comment: so what i need to do?.can u please tell me.